# Testing with spring xd and rabbit transport

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-xd

I am writing  some automation ruby scripts to test the streams and messages in queue.
My stream looks like

```
source| processor| processor| sink
```

Spring xd creates 3 internal queues.Now i have written ruby consumer to hook to these internal queues to test messages after every module(source/sink/processor).I  see that  when I   post 100 message to my source Some message are getting lost in my ruby client consumer because they are flowing in stream .I think the message are going to the next module ie processor .Is there any way i  can get all the message  in my ruby client and test them  and then I  can make those message flow through the stream.Is there a way such that multiple consumers can receive same message.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are registering other consumers on the bus queues, they will compete with the modules for messages.

I suppose that you are looking for a tap: http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#_taps

Hope this helps,
Marius